# Azure: Requested operation cannot be performed because storage account type 'Premium_LRS' is not supported for VM size

Tags: .net, azure

I'm creating virtual machines programmatically (.NET Fluent API, REST) and can't seem to find a way to get the sizes that are compatible with the Premium_LRS storage account type. The Fluent API and REST API both provide a way to get all sizes for a region, but there's nothing in the response that indicates the compatibility with a storage account type. Is there a way to get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard for regular VMs, Premium for VMs with the `s` letter in name: DS-series, DSv2-series, GS-series, Ls-series, Fs-series and B-series VMs. Notice B series are technically B1S, B4MS, etc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/premium-storage#supported-vms